# Can plain sockets be used on a web server?

Tags: c#, sockets

Can plain sockets be used on a web server. I've made a client/server application that uses a TCP connection for communication on port 10000. I just wanted to know that if i want to deploy that to a web server will i have to change from plain socket to web socket?

Comment: Do you even know what a web socket is?

Comment: I just heard about it. That it works on port 80.

Comment: This cannot be answered as is. If you have an application, why would you change it into a web application? Or are you asking if it can be put on a server which has a web server on it? Web sockets and TCP sockets are totally different and which you use depends on what you're doing. You don't just switch between them.

Comment: Yiour question doesn't make any sense. "Web sockets" and "plain sockets" have nothing to do with each other and are not interchangeable in any fashion.

Comment: Ignore the other answers. A webpage uses HTTP protocol.  The transport Layer for HTTP is TCP.  TCP has a maximum datagram size of 1500 bytes.  So HTTP request/response normally consists of multiple TCP datagrams.  A webpage normally uses port 80 or port 8080 but can be sent on any port number.  If you go to Code Project there are a number of samples where TCP is uses to send HTTPS (SSL).

Comment: @jdweng thanks for the answer